# Could not migrate JSON Datatype

Tags: laravel, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

When i am trying to use `$table->json('custom_data')->nullable();` in migration. Its throwing following error on running `php artisan migrate` command:

```
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42704]: Undefined object: 7 ERROR:  type "json" does not exist at character 236")
```

Versions:

```
Laravel 6.2
PostgreSQL 9.1.1

PostgreSQL(libpq) Version 9.6
```

Comment: Share your code and sample data

Comment: Use `jsonb` instead of `json` if you PostgreSQL's version less than 9.4 `$table->jsonb('custom_data')->nullable();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since the version 9.2, PostgreSQL supports the data type JSON

[gab.lc](https://www.gab.lc/articles/json_postgresql/).

so PostgreSQL 9.1.1 does not support json data type

you have to upgrade you PostgreSQL version to accept json columns
see [docs.bmc.com](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/btco113/migrating-the-data-from-postgresql-9-x-to-10-x-800581922.html)